# UserControl Plugins using System.Add

Tags: c#, .net, plugins, add-in, appdomain

I know the there is plenty of threads about loading plugins in new app domain. My fault I didn't read them before.. I have this school project - plugin based app, which is almost done. Except one important point - plugins has to be loaded in new domain.. I create plugin based app using this article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6334/Plug-ins-in-C

I'm currently in time press with project deadline and i'm stucked with plugin in same application domain. In previous thread has been adviced to to use System.AddIn (I expected that) but, there is little think - i couldn find if its possible use plugins which contains UserControl elements using System.AddIn

Thank you for all your advices.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe System.AddIn is a bit overkill for a school project. It has a quite high learning curve. I believe you are on the right track. You need to understand the basics on how to:

- Create a new AppDomain
- Make your add-in class derive from MarshalByRefObject
- Create an instance of the add-in class on the new AppDomain.

The rest of your program will be oblivious of all this. It will be the same because you will be using a proxy object on the main AppDomain while the actual add-in object will be on the new AppDomain. All the infrastructure is taken care of .Net Remoting.

Regards.

Comment: Thank you Panos for your answer. I'll try to look at this hovewer i dont know how to combinate the extendet AddIn clas with PluginInterface etc. .. :( Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: The example you mention cannot be properly converted to load add-ins in a new AppDomain because the IPlugin interface includes a UserControl property (MainInterface). According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bxxy49h.aspx), Windows Form Controls are not designed to be passed accross application domain boundaries. So we cannot make this example work as it is. If we remove the UserControl and just keep the other properties then it is not that hard. I can show you how to do this, if you are still interested. But with no UserControl, just Name, Description etc.